# Getting start with Node, Express, and Bootstrap

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

I've started reading up on Node and Express with the intention of porting a few projects of mine over to it. The projects I'm porting are currently built with Python and Flask, and styled with Bootstrap.

I'm having difficulties getting a basic Express site up and running with Bootstrap as the styling. I used [express-generator](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) to get the basic skeleton set up, and then used *npm* to install bootstrap:

```
npm install bootstrap
```

I added bootstrap as a requirement, and as a middleware:

```
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
app.use('bootstrap');
```

Now I'm just not sure how to "import" that into my layout template. If someone could show me an example, or point me to a resource, that'd be great.

Comment: Can you not just use bootstrap via html (in your layout) using one of Bootstraps [CDNs](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/), or by putting bootstrap in your `/public` folder?

Answer (score 1):

Nodejs is used on the backend there is no need to npm install bootstrap. Node will serve your html or jade/pug/ejs etc.

You can use a CDN and link the files in the html or pug. You can also choose to include the CSS and JS files required for bootstrap in the /public directory.

Using the Express generator is a great start, you can specify your templating engine (i.e. jade/pug, ejs etc.) or just use html. Jade/Pug will compile into HTML and be served to the front end (client side). You can include the CDN link within your jade/pug file, similar to how you would include it in regular HTML. You might want to read some documentation for pug/jade since it has a more minimalistic syntax than html, [Pug Docs.](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html)

To use pug/jade enter the following command (provided you have express generator npm installed already):

```
express --pug --css
```

To use html only enter the following command (provided you have express generator npm installed already):

```
express --no-view --css
```

The commands above will create the template, all you have to do is include the CDN link within the /view/layout.pug file and you can use bootstrap. Basic routing has been defined, just `npm install`, and `npm start`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need bootstrap as a node module since bootstrap is a front end thing. You'd be better off doing a bower.
Goto your terminal

```
sudo npm install bower -g
```

Then, once you have that make a .bowerrc file

```
nano .bowerrc
```

set the default directory as public in that file

```
{
"directory":"./public"
}
```

Then, finally, do this-

```
bower install bootstrap --save
```

That will fetch bootstrap for your styles. If you want to pass data from the server to the htmls, try one of the templating engines like ejs or jade and then later add the cols in there to be rendered as html to the client.